# Plot estimated function?

Tags: r, plot, logistic-regression

I need help interpreting this (it's part of an assignment which I'm stuck with):

*"Create a plot for each subject where you plot the estimated function (on the *target.contrast* range from 0-1) based on the fitted values of a model (use `glm`) that models *correct* as dependent on *target.contrast*."*

The variables:

- *subject*: values 1:36 naming each subject
- *target* contrast: Continuous variable having values in the range 0-1
- *correct*: Binary variable: either 0 or 1

Length of data set is 5,000 rows.

Now to my question: What do you think is meant by 'estimated function'? Random intercepts? Estimated values? I'm quite confused.

So far, I've made this:

```
# modelling correct as dependent on target.contrast
model1 <- glmer(correct ~ target.contrast + (1 | subject), data = exp2_staircase, family = binomial)

plot(exp2_staircase$target.contrast, model1$fitted.values, xlab='Target contrast',
     ylab='Probability of being correct/incorrect',
     main='Logistic regression - fitted values')
```

**Example data**

```
#   subject    target.contrast correct
# 1     001         0.04370244       1
# 2     002         0.04370244       1
# 3     003         0.06284581       0
# 4     004         0.14405043       1 
# 5     005         0.10045633       0
# 6     006         0.06274573       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the requirement is to use a `glm` for each group (here: manufacturer), we can do exactly this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

estimates <-
  mpg %>%
  nest(-manufacturer) %>%
  mutate(
    model = data %>% map(~  glm(displ ~ hwy, data = .x)),
    estimates = model %>% map2(data, ~ .x %>% predict(newdata = .y))
  ) %>%
  select(manufacturer, data, estimates) %>%
  unnest(estimates) %>%
  unnest(data) %>%
  mutate(displ = estimates) %>%
  distinct(manufacturer, hwy, .keep_all = TRUE)
#> Warning: All elements of `...` must be named.
#> Did you want `data = c(model, displ, year, cyl, trans, drv, cty, hwy, fl, class)`?
    
bind_rows(
  mpg %>% mutate(type = "truth"),
  estimates %>% mutate(type = "predicted")
) %>%
  filter(manufacturer %in% c("audi", "volkswagen")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(hwy, displ, color = type, shape = manufacturer)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Random factors are only used, if the prediction is based on new groups the model has not seen yet.

Comment: First: Thanks for taking time to help! Secondly: I myself wonder if it's a mistake that it says 'use glm', since using a mixed effects model makes so much more sense (since we're dealing with multiple participants having individual baselines). Also we dealing with a binary outcome variable - shouldn't we make a logistic regression then? I'm not able to replicate your code on my data for some reason... But my goodness you're a master at tidyverse!

Comment: You must give us example data so we have something to work on. Since you have a binary outcome, it is indeed a good idea to use a binomial family. It's more of the perspective you have on the data whether to model a variable as random or fixed. You can do it both ways during fitting.

Comment: Now I've added example of data (just multiply it with 1000, to get the actually no of rows in data).

Comment: Use `dput(exp2_staircase)` so it's easier for us to load the data into our own environment.